# How to enable "Require Authentication" in Firebase Cloud Functions (Python)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

i try to write in Firebase a Cloud Function, which by default require authentication like normal cloud functions:

[image: Normal Cloud Function]

With classic Cloud Functions this is default and easy to achive, but with Firebase Cloud Functions i find no way to get it done.

My code looks like:

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
@https_fn.on_request(region="europe-west1") 
def hello_world(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response(f"Hello World")
```

but if i deploy my function (`firebase deploy`) it is always a public endpoint which allows unauthenticated invocations.

How can i change this???

PS: My big Goal is a function, which i can only call from the cloud shell (for admin stuff) But i want all my functions in one place so i want to define it inside my firebase project with my other cloud functions

Thank you for any help :D

Till know i found no solution my goal is something like this:

[image: permission denied]

instead of:

[image: permission allowed]

Comment: The Firebase CLI defaults to functions with public access because that's what a vast majority of Firebase developers need - a public endpoint to support their web and mobile app.  A non-public function with GCP IAM auth doesn't fit in with that.  If you want a way to change this default when deploying with the Firebase CLI, you might want to file a feature request in the [firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  If Firebase chooses to implement this, it will likely be a runtime option you configure in your code.

Comment: If you are not willing to wait for this to be implemented (there is no guarantee), you could still use a public function, and require that the caller provide some sort of credential in the request that authorizes the function to execute normally, otherwise reject the request.